# Primitive roots $\pmod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am studying primitive roots.

I don't know if I understood well: if a number $a$ is a primitive root $\pmod p$, for $p$ prime, then $a$ is a generator of units $\pmod p$, that is $a^j$ generates all the numbers $(<p)$ coprime with $p$? Is that right?
If $a$ is NOT a primitive root, then this does not happen? Did I understand well?

Comment: $a$ is a primitive root of prime $p \Leftrightarrow$ $a$ has multiplicative order $p-1$ in $Z_p$

Comment: that is correct!

Answer (score 1):

Primitive roots or generators are the elements of the Groups, when you use p as prime number it creates the field, and number of elements in the fields are ${\phi(p)=(p-1)}$,
, because every number < p are relative prime to p, the field contains elements from ${\{1,..,p-1\}}$,

- Now generators are the elements of Group G (field in case of p is prime), which generators all the elements of Field.
- Multiplicative field, ${{Z_p}^*}$, is cyclic, as every elements of the field can be written in form of  ${a^n}$,for some ${n \in Z}$, (i.e.,if the map ${f:Z \mapsto G}$ such that ${f(n)=a^n }$ is surjective, such an element ${a}$ of ${G}$ or field ${F}$ is called generator/primitive root of Group or Field.
- if m is a number of elements in Group/Field(i.e, order of Group/Field) then ${gcd(a,m)=1}$ and there is no ${i<m, i \in Z}$ gives ${a^i=1(modp)}$